# How to animate a Line Graph in plotly using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, linechart, gganimate

Example:
Date_Time
<S3: POSIXct>
Total.Active.Power

2023-06-09 15:26:55  0.500
2023-06-09 15:26:59  0.500
2023-06-09 15:27:02  1.000
2023-06-09 15:27:05  1.500
2023-06-09 15:27:09  0.500
2023-06-09 15:27:12  2.000

I want to animate this so the line graph moves with time but using plotly.

I used gganimate

```
pv1_table_plot <- pv1_table %>% ggplot( aes(x = Date_Time, y = Total.Active.Power)) +
  geom_line(color = 'blue', size = 2)
animated_plot <- pv1_table_plot +
   transition_reveal(Date_Time)
```

Result:

[image]

How can I use Plotly to create an animated line graph with time-based animation, so that the line moves along with time? Additionally, I would like the animation to include hover details showing the data points.

Comment: @maydin I'm not able to recreate it . 
CH4 <- dts %>% accumulate_by(~X) This code is from the link you provided. How do you know which one to choose instead "X"

Comment: There is also another [link](https://plotly.com/r/cumulative-animations/) provided inside the question above.

Comment: @maydin Still getting plot with no lines but frame is moving. The date_Time values in my dataset is in posixct type. Is it due to that?
I took `accumulate_by(date_time)`